# How to calculating time difference

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a program where i put in to different times and get the difference in minute after clicking the "calculate" button. I'm not sure if my approach is correct, there may be some typo's.

I'v tried to make the different input values to number but it seems like there is another underlying problem which I can't see.

```js
var hour1=document.getElementById("hour1");
var min1=document.getElementById("min1");
var hour2=document.getElementById("hour2");
var min2=document.getElementById("min2");

function calc(){
    var minutt1=Number(hour1)*60+Number(min1);
    var minutt2=Number(hour2)*60+Number(min2);
    var resultat=0;
    resultat = Number(minutt1) - Number(minutt2);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Time differance is:" + Number(resultat);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="hour1">:
<input type="number" id="min1"> - 
<input type="number" id="hour2">:
<input type="number" id="min1">
<button type="button" onclick="calc()">Regn ut</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

I expect getting a number which represents the time difference in minutes, but the actual output is "NaN".

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the `value` of `hour1`, `min1`, `hour2`, and `min2`. You also don't have an element `min2`:

```
var hour1=document.getElementById("hour1").value;
var min1=document.getElementById("min1").value;
var hour2=document.getElementById("hour2").value;
var min2=document.getElementById("min2").value;
```

What your code was trying to do was multiply and subtract HTML elements (never a good idea).

```js
var hour1 = document.getElementById("hour1").value;
var min1 = document.getElementById("min1").value;
var hour2 = document.getElementById("hour2").value;
var min2 = document.getElementById("min2").value;

function calc() {
  var minutt1 = Number(hour1) * 60 + Number(min1);
  var minutt2 = Number(hour2) * 60 + Number(min2);
  var resultat = 0;
  resultat = Number(minutt1) - Number(minutt2);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Time differance is:" + Number(resultat);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="hour1">:
<input type="number" id="min1"> -
<input type="number" id="hour2">:
<input type="number" id="min2">
<button type="button" onclick="calc()">Regn ut</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are close, but you need to get the **value** of the inputs **after** you click the button

```js
var hour1 = document.getElementById("hour1");
var min1 = document.getElementById("min1");
var hour2 = document.getElementById("hour2");
var min2 = document.getElementById("min2");

window.calc = function () {
  var minutt1 = parseInt(hour1.value) * 60 + parseInt(min1.value);
  var minutt2 = parseInt(hour2.value) * 60 + parseInt(min2.value);
  var resultat = minutt1 - minutt2;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Time differance is:" + resultat;
  
  console.log({minutt1:minutt1,minutt2:minutt2,resultat:resultat,
  hour1:hour1,min1:min1,
  hour2:hour2,min2:min2
  })
};
```

```html
<input type="number" id="hour1">:
<input type="number" id="min1"> -
<input type="number" id="hour2">:
<input type="number" id="min2">
<button type="button" onclick="calc()">Regn ut</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```